# Android Communication: Phone to Phone Application Control over 3G

Tags: android, android-c2dm, gprs

I'm currently working on an android project and I am trying to find the best way to go about setting up communication between two android phones.

One android phone will be docked on a mobile platform e.g. an R/C car. I want this phone to receive simple control signals ("forward", "backward", "left", "right", "gotoCoordinate") sent from another android phone. I also want the docked phone to be able to return status signals.

Preferably I want the communication to happen via GPRS. I'm aware of the difficulties concerning P2P-communications and I'm currently looking into "Android Cloud To Device Messaging." (http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html)

I'd like to hear about your experience with Android C2DM (glad to hear about delay from transmit to receive) and your thoughts on utilizing it in my project. I'd appreciate other suggestions on how to go about this. I'm expecting to have to deal with relatively high latency using this method, but of course preferably lowest possible.

Answer (score 1):

C2DM makes no guarantee about the "delivery or order" of the messages, and it is limited in the number of messages you can send (a high limit, but still a limit). It's not really for low-latency stuff like controlling an RC car. It's better for non-realtime events.

http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

For lower latency stuff using GPRS you can setup a third party server on your own and have both phones communicate through it. I've done that for several Android apps using straight up TCP sockets and it works reasonably well (and it would be even faster/better if you went UDP). Using GPRS may still have too much latency, depending on your needs, but it's a tradeoff (it's very convenient, almost always there, other methods are not).

The ideal way to do this would be to combine whatever is available and fallback gracefully, and test the latency once connected to make sure the network is up to par, or bail out. For example, use the local WiFi network if it's available. That is to say, have both devices "register" with a third party server as they startup, then if they're both on the same WiFi just have them communicate directly (run a server on or both, and clients on one or both, get information about discovery and such from the registration). If they are not on WiFi then fall back to GPRS, but realize there will be more latency, of course. Finally, once any method has been established send some test messages to check latency.

I know this isn't really an "answer," it's more of a stream of consciousness about this, but it wouldn't fit in a comment, and I thought it might help ;).

(Full disclosure: I've worked on Android apps that connect multiple mobile devices and multiple TVs, some over GPRS, some Wifi, some directly. I work for a company (MOVL) that makes a platform for stuff like that, it's more focused on mobile-TV-mobile, but it supports mobile-mobile also. In all it's not too hard to do yourself with regular networking, the tricky part is getting the latency down and picking the correct method for each device.)